# Cannot find library, even though it is on search path

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker, makefile, shared-libraries

In Ubuntu 14.04, I have downloaded some source code which comes with a makefile. I have then run "make" on it to compile, which builds an executable. When executing this file, I receive the following error:

```
./mt_test: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now, the file `libcudart.so.7.0` is located in the directory `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64`. But in my `.bashrc` file, I have the line: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Furthermore, if I run `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the terminal, one of the entries is this path. There are no other copies of `libcudart.so.7.0` elsewhere on my system.

Is there any reason why the executable might not be able find this library, even though its directory is one of the search directories?

Strangely, this error has only happened since installing Matlab on my system. There is now a file called `libcudart.so.6.5` located at `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64`, but this path is not part of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: is there a `libcudart.so.7.0` in that directory? maybe it's really `libcudart.so.7.0.1.2.3.4.5.6` and no symlink to the "plain" `.so.7.0` was established. or so.7.0 symlink exists, but is dangling.

Comment: No, the only `libcudart.so.7.0` on my entire system is in `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64`.

Comment: what does ldd ./mt_test say?

Comment: Maybe a 332bit/64bit issue?  Is the `mt_test` program a 64bit binary?  Use `file mt_test` and see if it reports i386 or x86_64.  Your `libcudart` is a 64bit library so if `mt_test` is a 32bit binary it won't work.  However, I'm surprised it linked in the first place if you don't have / can't find the right shared library.  Unless it's using `dlopen()` to access the library not the runtime linker?

Answer (score 1):

As MadScientist probably correctly guessed, this is likely a 32 vs. 64-bit mismatch. Run the following command:

```
file -L ./mt_test /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64/libcudart.so.7.0
```

The command should report either `ELF 32-bit LSB ...`, or `ELF 64-bit LSB ...` for *both* files. If one of the files is 32-bit, and the other 64-bit, then they are not compatible.

You can gain further insight into where the dynamic linker is searching for `libcudart.so.7.0` by running the following command:

```
LD_DEBUG=files,libs ./mt_test
```